# Anonymous and Forms Authentication IIS 7

Tags: authentication, iis-7

First of, sorry for not posting any actual code, but I just want to be pointed in some direction. Might post code later if needed.

So, I have 3 applications running in IIS

1 - Application itself
2 - Authentication and Access Management
3 - NTLM

All use application pool with framework 2.0 Classic Mode.

1 and 2 uses annonymous and form authentication, 
3 uses windows authentication.

The flow is, when you access 1 or 2, it redirects to NTLM for auth and returns with the authentication.

If I access the first one its all good, it goes to the ntlm and even if I dont have a valid windows account it returns to the app login page.

When I try to access the second one I get a redirect loop from the ntlm to the login page to the ntlm and so on...

Both have the same configuration.

I know this might not be very explicit, but I going insane over this and don't now where more to look.

Answer (score 0):

Weird as it may sound, when setting the machineKey on web.config, I put decryption="Auto", which is totally normal... because it's the same setting in IIS console. But that was causing the error in event viewer saying invalid ticket.

Still can't figure out why... anyway if someone come across this same weird issue, here you have what I have done. I took out that "decryption" setting from web.config